# Problem in applying less than criteria in Autofilter for dates in German local setting

Tags: excel, vba

I got a problem in applying Autofilter in german local settings , less than or greater than  criteria  for dates with format dd.mm.yyyy through macro, It is not working as intended. manually filter works but when I run through my macro code it filters nothing . but it works fine if I manually click ok (no change being applied to the filter criteria), it starts filtering correctly.

Same code works for English local settings.

Here is my code

```
Dim myDate as String
myDate  = "20.10.2016"

filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<" & myDate
```

I have tried with below code still not working ...

```
Dim myDate as String
myDate  = "20.10.2016"

filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<" & CDate(myDate)
```

But its works fine with equal to criteria

```
filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="=" & myDate
```

Comment: I can replicate this. Even if I record this as a macro and play it back it doesn't work. Even though it gets recorded as `Criteria1:=">20.10.2016"`. It does however work with US date format: `Criteria1:=">10/20/2016"`. I guess you would have to take the extra step and convert your date to US date format before applying the filter.

Comment: @horst Not necessary to convert dates into other language, as [CDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions) recognizes date formats according to the locale setting of your system. If you additionally typecast it to a `CDbl`, then it works for `AutoFilter`.

Comment: @Ranjitha Did you give my answer a try? If it works fine for you, please do me a favor and mark the checkbox beneath it (see [someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)). If not, don't hesitate to comment below it.

Answer (score 3):

Date filtering in non-English Excel works, when you typecast a datetime value as `Double`:

```
filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<" & CDbl(myDate)
```

Following also works with date notation in your language, as [CDate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions) recognizes date formats according to the locale setting of your system (example: 3rd of July 2015 in German notation):

```
filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="<" & CDbl(CDate("3.7.15"))
```

Be aware that criteria <, <=, >, >=, <> will work like above, but if dates must be filtered equal to a given date, a simple "=..." either needs the **exact notation** of the dates in your worksheet (depending of the number format of the cells) or following, independent of date format:

```
filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=13, _
    Criteria1:="<=" & CDbl(myDate), Operator:=xlAnd, _
    Criteria2:=">=" & CDbl(myDate)
```